# How to plot a histogram in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram

I have one vector (`newdata`) consisting of 4100 lines and one column. To be exact, those elements are the counts of a spectrum. What I want is to reproduce the spectrum using MATLAB. That's why I created a new vector:

```
channels=[1:size(newdata,1)];
```

I tried to plot the spectrum (using `channel` in x axis and `newdata` as a weight) by typing:

```
hist(channels,newdata)
```

But I got an error

```
??? Error using ==> histc
Edges vector must be monotonically non-decreasing.

Error in ==> hist at 86
    nn = histc(y,[-inf bins],1);
```

How can I draw the desired spectrum?

Comment: With 4100 points, a bar chart will just look like a solid area (unless your monitor is HUGE!)... Why not just use `plot`?

Comment: This cannot be called weighted histogram by the way...

Comment: @wakjah: Actually it really worked! The output is found here http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/7551/42042502.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try plotting using the `bar` command

```
bar( channels, newData );
```